# how do i put date orderly on each button?

Tags: android, date, button, calendar

I have 7 buttons. On the first button I display the current date, on the second button I want it to display the date of tomorrow, on the third one the date after that, and so on.

I tried several times using `Calendar` but the app close when this activity open. can someone show me how to use `Calendar` on my case ? or how to solve this ?

```
public class OrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button dateButton1, dateButton2;

Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
Date today = new Date();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);

    dateButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    dateButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);


    int amount = 1; // amount of days you want to add to the current date

    SimpleDateFormat formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM");

    today.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis()); //set to current date
    dateButton1.setText(formattedDate.format(today));


    //this code below cause app stoped when this activity start
    calender.add(Calendar.DATE, amount);
    String newDate = (String)(formattedDate.format(calender.getTime()));

    dateButton2.setText(formattedDate.format(newDate));

}}
```

This was my last build, how can I apply the next date on dateButton2, the date after that on dateButton3 and so on?

so far when enter this activity app closed and this is on the logcat

```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date
                                                                       at java.text.DateFormat.format(DateFormat.java:306)
                                                                       at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
```

PS: sorry for bad English

Comment: Post the crash logs please.

Comment: Consider throwing out the long outdated classes `Date`, `Calendar` and in particular the notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and adding [the ThreeTenABP library](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Andoird project in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: can you help me usung the threetenABP but using my case ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
public class OrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button dateButton1, dateButton2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_order);

    Date date = new Date();

    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy/MM/dd");  

    LocalDateTime today = LocalDateTime.now(); 
    LocalDate tomorrow = LocalDate.now().plusDays(1);

    // LocalDate dayAfterTomorrow = LocalDate.now().plusDays(2);
    // continue like this

    dateButton1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button5);
    dateButton2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button6);

    dateButton1.setText(dtf.format(now)));
    dateButton2.setText(dtf.format(tomorrow)));
}

}
```

Comment: Did you think that this code would get the output as 7 buttons which shows 7 dates like @avid _ kupit asked?

Comment: What? It now shows 2 dates on 2 buttons, he just needs to update the code with more buttons.

Comment: not working, same with other aproach it close when activity used, same to in logcat

Answer (score 1):

### java.time and ThreeTenABP

> can you help me usung the threetenABP but using my case ?

This should get you in the right direction:

```
    DateTimeFormatter dateFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M-d");
    ZoneId zone = ZoneId.of("Asia/Jayapura");
    LocalDate date = LocalDate.now(zone);
    int amount = 1; // amount of days you want to add to the current date
    int buttonCount = 7;
    for (int i = 0; i < buttonCount; i++) {
        System.out.println(date.format(dateFormatter));
        date = date.plusDays(amount);
    }
```

Output when I ran the code just now:

```
10-17
10-18
10-19
10-20
10-21
10-22
10-23
```

My imports were:

```
import org.threeten.bp.LocalDate;
import org.threeten.bp.ZoneId;
import org.threeten.bp.format.DateTimeFormatter;
```

### What went wrong in your code?

You tried this:

```
    String newDate = (String)(formattedDate.format(calender.getTime()));

    dateButton2.setText(formattedDate.format(newDate));
```

`newDate` is already formatted into a `String`, so it doesn’t make sense to do it once more. The `format` method accepts a `Date` or a `Long`, but not a `String`.

### Links

- [Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use `java.time`.
- [Java Specification Request (JSR) 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310), where `java.time` was first described.
- [ThreeTen Backport project](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/), the backport of `java.time` to Java 6 and 7 (ThreeTen for JSR-310).
- [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP), Android edition of ThreeTen Backport
- [Question: How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project), with a very thorough explanation.

Comment: haloo, i use your suggestion and it works. but the output got 26 27 28 etc. which is wrong because today is 20 not 26. did you know why ? 
i use ZoneId "Asia/Jakarta" btw

Comment: In case other readers are curious: @avid_kupit’s issue is [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59849138/why-localdate-value-didnt-set-on-today-date)

Comment: thanks [Ole.vv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5772882/ole-v-v) for hellp, really appreciated sir

Comment: No need to mention it, @avid_kupit, I don’t think I really contributed anything in this round.

Answer (score 0):

You're using wrong format. your format will have months only. however you can increment days by using the following code.

```
Date today = new Date();
int amount = 1; // amount of days you want to add to the current date          
SimpleDateFormat formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");            
Calendar calender = Calendar.getInstance();
// add to the current date
calender.add(Calendar.DATE, amount);    
String newDate = (String)(formattedDate.format(calender.getTime()));
System.out.println("newDate date is " + newDate);
```

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Date



.........app stoped, and this on debug console, any idea why ?